# What happens exported member's value changed after require() function called (NodeJS)?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Recently I' am studying 'NodeJs Module System (CommonJS)', and found something weird about `require()` function. First, Let's look at sample code, 'exporter.js'

```
var c;
module.exports= c ;

c = {
    c_key1: 100
};
c .c_key1=0;
```

As you can see, `module.exports=c`  statement appears before reassignment to variable `c`. So I guessed if I import `module.exports` on 'test.js' and refer to c_key1 , there would be reference error!! Here is 'test.js'

```
const exporter = require('./exporter.js');
console.log(exporter.c_key1);
```

And as I said, there was reference error.

```
console.log(exporter.c_key1);
                     ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'c_key1' of undefined
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Javascript-Workspace\JSGrammar\test.js:2:22)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:769:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:72:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47
```

And, I tested example with another 'exporter.js' (as below...).

```
var c;
c = {
    c_key1: 100
};
module.exports= c ;
c .c_key1=0;
```

And because of 1st example, this time, I also guessed if I refer to `c_key1` in 'test.js', it would return value of 100 (no 0...).But, result in 'test.js' says like below...

```
0
```

Ummmm, I can't understand. I thought statements only before the assignment to `module.exports` is valid. But 2nd example seems to say it isn't... Can you tell me what is correct answer??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both behaviours are correct.

The below code does not do what you think it does:

```
var c;
module.exports= c ;

c = {
    c_key1: 100
};
c .c_key1=0;
```

When you do `c = {...` you **do not** re-assign the exported value. The exported value has already been exported as `undefined`.

It's kind of like this:

```
var n;
var m = n;
n = 0;
console.log(m); // m is still undefined
```

Comment: Oh,... come to think of it, I misunderstood the concept of 'mutable' and 'unmutable' type in JavaScript!!!! Thanks for your nice comment!!

Answer (score 1):

It comes down to the value types you are exporting. In your first example, you export `undefined`, in your second example you export an object. When you require this module in both scenarios you end up with the value you are exporting. The only difference is that you can mutate the object without changing the export value. In other words, you change the contents of the object even though you are still exporting the same object.

Comment: Thank you for your nice comment. Suerly, I didn;t even think that primitive data type is unmutable !!!